# What should be the value of x, y, z in the grid?

Tags: pattern, visual

What should be the value of x,y, and z?
Don't forget to explain the rule.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values are

> X= ABC and Z  = BBC , as in each row,  column and both the diagonals the counts of A, B, C is 3.

So it follows that

> Y = AA

Comment: No.. still wrong.

Comment: @Jamal...corrected my answer. Pls. check

Comment: No.. still wrong.

Comment: Oops. Again edited.

Comment: previous answer is better then now. but still wrong

Answer (score 1):

> Z= CBB , Y = AA, X = ABC
>  If we take all the alphabets individually, (a,b,c) are occurring thrice in every row and column respectively with a total of 9 alphabets in each row and column.
>  The order of the alphabets in z is correct because of the pattern in row1, row3 and row4 ( single alphabets is with two same alphabets, a is with bb and cc with a leading once (ABB) and a at the end other time (CCA) )

Comment: Mea Culpa Nay, find the rule first, so the tick mark for him.